# How to print all variables in an object, and how to print a select set of variables?

Tags: c++, class, object, variables

```
class Person
{
public:
        string fname;
        string lname;
        string occupation;
        string gender;
        int age;
};
int main()
{
        Person bc;
        bc.fname = "Bevelry";
        bc.lname = "Crusher";
        bc.gender = "female";
        bc.occupation = "Doctor, USS 1701-D";
        bc.age = 40;
        cout << bc.all << "\n"; //Something like this?
}
```

Is it possible for me to print every variable of an object without specifying them by myself? And is it possible for me to make a select list of variables, something like an array of variables, and then print them?

EDIT: i accidently put the cout in the class, fixed now

Comment: No, C++ does not (yet) have reflection

Comment: I suspect this to be a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem I cannot think of a situation in which all attributes of an object should be output, without any representation details. Apart from debugging purposes, i.e. on a meta level of desire to see all values. For debuggin on the other hand I recommend using a debugger. So please provide details on the more abstract level of what you want to achieve. Because even if I am wrong in my guess, a larger change to the design of your program might get you what you want, without doing it the way you thought of.

Comment: @Yunnosch There's nothing specific i'm trying to achieve this for, i'm just wondering if i can do it or not.

Comment: If that is the case, the comment by UnholySheep is your answer. (But I doubt it.)

Comment: @0b11001001 Did you get your questions answered by the answers below? If so, please accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for me to print every variable of an object without specifying them by myself?

No.

> And is it possible for me to make a select list of variables, something like an array of variables, and then print them?

Not automatically, but you could create a collection of [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)s and add some decoding for it yourself.

Example:

```
#include <any>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// decode and print one std::any
void decode_one(std::ostream& os, const std::any& a) {
    if(auto s = std::any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>(&a)) os << s->get();
    else if(auto i = std::any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<int>>(&a)) os << *i;
    else if(auto d = std::any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<double>>(&a)) os << *d;
    // add more types to decode here
    else os << "<unknown type>";
}

// a custom ostream operator to decode a vector of anys:
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::any>& va) {
    auto begin = va.begin();
    auto end = va.end();
    if(begin != end) {
        decode_one(os, *begin);
        for(std::advance(begin, 1); begin != end; std::advance(begin, 1)) {
            os << ',';
            decode_one(os, *begin);
        }
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    std::string b = "Hello world";
    double c = 3.14159;

    std::vector<std::any> va{
        std::ref(a),
        std::ref(b),
        std::ref(c)
    };
    
    c *= 2.;                 // just to show that the vector holds a reference

    std::cout << va << '\n'; // print the variables in the vector
}
```

Output:

```
10,Hello world,6.28318
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. In C++ there isn't anything that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

At one side one can easily say that this is not possible in C++.

However, at the other side, one can add that this situation happens quite often when people are making object oriented computer programs, and in Java there is [the `toString()` method](https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method) for this. So, you might actually write your own `toString()` method (based on the way it is done in Java), and work with this.

Good luck